# Phonegap cordova navigator.camera.getPicture onfail not getting called in iphone

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

am using cordova phonegap to build a mobile app. In my code I have used the below line,

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI }); 
}

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Now in iphone, when I press a button to open the gallery and then press cancel, my app comes back to the page where I have given the button. Then, how many ever times I press the button to choose from gallery, it won't happen! The click on button is just not responsive. It works perfectly fine in Android

Comment: I've tested your code and it's working fine for me. Which cameara plugin version did you use?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @jcesarmobile. I just added the plugin name in cordova's config.xml. It should take the latest right. But my issue just got resolved when I used navigator.camera.cleanup() before the getPicture() method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue just got resolved when I used navigator.camera.cleanup() before the getPicture() method